# Symfony 3.0 errors are coming back in French language? I am not sure why

Tags: php, symfony

symfony doctrine errors coming back in french, I don't understand the error. I searched google and I can't find why is it coming back in french.

like this " 1064 Erreur de syntaxe près "

Comment: The language was coming from mysql file my.ini 

lc-messages=fr_FR

changed it to 

lc-messages=en_US

Answer (score 0):

The language was coming from mysql file `my.ini`

I resolved it by changing`lc-messages=fr_FR`to `lc-messages=en_US`